# How to embed a bokeh plot in web2py

Tags: python, web2py, bokeh

I have wasted quite some time and am unable to embed a bokeh plot in my web2py app.

My current code:

```
def plot():
    from bokeh.plotting import figure
    from bokeh.resources import CDN
    from bokeh.embed import file_html

    plot = figure()
    plot.circle([1,2], [3,4])

    html = file_html(plot, CDN, "my plot")
    return (html)
```

But nothing happens. I would be grateful for any tipe of example, it doesn't have to be nothing special. Just a simple graph.

Kind regards

Comment: We need more code. How are you calling the `plot` function and attempting to insert its output into the page?

Comment: I am calling the plot function by simple going to www. - ... - /default/plot. I have not created a page specifically for the plot function since 1. I was hoping it would be done somehow on its own 2. I have no idea how to embed a graph onto a page.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `html` is a string (of HTML markup). When a web2py action returns a string, that string is returned directly to the browser. If you are attempting to load that HTML as a complete web page, it will not work, as the Bokeh `file_html` function simply produces a `<script>` tag with Javascript code. It only works if you embed it within a complete HTML page and load the Bokeh Javascript and CSS files in the page. For further details, please see the relevant [Bokeh documentation](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html).

To make this work in web2py, you can use `response.files` to include the necessary Bokeh Javascript and CSS files, and you can embed the Bokeh-generated script tag in a view.

```
def plot():
    from bokeh.plotting import figure
    from bokeh.resources import CDN
    from bokeh.embed import file_html

    response.files.extend(list_of_Bokeh_JS_and_CSS_static_file_URLs)

    plot = figure()
    plot.circle([1,2], [3,4])

    html = file_html(plot, CDN, "my plot")
    return dict(bokeh_script=html)
```

It is up to you to specify the list of Bokeh JS and CSS files and ensure they are available (you can copy them to your web2py app's static folder and serve them from there or use the Bokeh CDN as shown in their docs).

Then in the view for the `plot` action (e.g., /views/default/plot.html):

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}

{{=XML(bokeh_script)}}
```

Note, when inserting a string of HTML markup directly into a web2py view, you must wrap it in `XML()` to prevent web2py from escaping the HTML.

Finally, assuming you have Python and Bokeh installed on your system, be sure to run web2py from source rather than using the Windows or OSX binaries, as the latter include their own Python interpreters and therefore cannot import libraries installed on your system.

Comment: Thank you so much. THis should probably do the trick. The only problem I have now is that I cannot get bokeh module into web2py. Any easy solution how I could fix that? Since there are no pip stuff.

Comment: I have updated the answer (next time, be sure to mention details like that in the original question). You can install Python libraries via pip and then import those libraries in web2py applications. However, you must be running web2py from source in order to use your system's Python installation -- the Windows and OSX binaries include their own Python interpreters and therefore ignore your system's Python installation.